# Fetch error from open weather api SwiftUI

Tags: swift, api

I'm trying to create a weather app with OpenWeatherAPI everything is working except the API I get this error:

```
{
    2021-07-08 00:52:39.222597+0300 WeatherApp[63294:1616825] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(144) Failed to log metrics
    keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "Weather", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "daily", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"Weather\", intValue: nil) (\"Weather\").", underlyingError: nil))
    decodingError(err: "The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.")
}
```

if you can help me with I will appreciate it 
I use this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KI6Yf7VMefc

```swift
extension API {
    static let baseURLString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/"

    static func getURLFor(lat: Double, lon: Double) -> String {
        return "\(baseURLString)onecall?lat=\(lat)&lon=\(lon)&exclude=minutely&appid=\(key)&units=imperial"
    }
}
```

```swift
final class NetworkManager<T: Codable> {
    static func fetch(for url: URL, completion: @escaping (Result<T, NetworkError>) -> Void) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print(String(describing: error!))
                completion(.failure(.error(err: error!.localizedDescription)))
                return
            }

            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                completion(.failure(.invalidResponse))
                return
            }

            guard let data = data else {
                completion(.failure(.invalidData))
                return
            }

            do {
                let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
                completion(.success(json))
            } catch let err {
                print(String(describing: err))
                completion(.failure(.decodingError(err: err.localizedDescription)))
            }

        }.resume()
    }
}
```

```swift
enum NetworkError: Error {
    case invalidResponse
    case invalidData
    case error(err: String)
    case decodingError(err: String)
}
```

```swift
struct WeatherResponse: Codable {
    var current: Weather
    var hourly: [Weather]
    var daily: [DailyWeather]

    static func empty() -> WeatherResponse {
        return WeatherResponse(current: Weather(), hourly: [Weather](repeating: Weather(), count: 23), daily: [DailyWeather](repeating: DailyWeather(), count: 8))
    }
}
```

```swift
struct Weather: Codable, Identifiable {
    var dt: Int
    var temp: Double
    var feels_like: Double
    var pressure: Int
    var humidity: Int
    var dew_point: Double
    var clouds: Int
    var wind_speed: Double
    var wind_deg: Int
    var weather: [WeatherDetail]

    enum CodingKey: String {
        case dt
        case temp
        case feels_like
        case pressure
        case humidity
        case dew_point
        case clouds
        case wind_speed
        case wind_deg
        case weather
    }

    init() {
        dt = 0
        temp = 0.0
        feels_like = 0.0
        pressure = 0
        humidity = 0
        dew_point = 0.0
        clouds = 0
        wind_speed = 0.0
        wind_deg = 0
        weather = []
    }
}

extension Weather {
    var id: UUID {
        return UUID()
    }
}
```

```swift
struct DailyWeather: Codable, Identifiable {
    var dt: Int
    var temp: Temp
    var Weather: [WeatherDetail]

    enum CodingKey: String {
        case dt
        case temp
        case weather
    }

    init(){
        dt = 0
        temp = Temp(min: 0.0, max: 0.0)
        Weather = [WeatherDetail(main: "", description: "", icon: "")]
    }
}

extension DailyWeather {
    var id: UUID {
        return UUID()
    }
}
```

Comment: `print(String(describing: err))`: Could you also print `String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)`?

Comment: The error is quite specific, it says the json has no key Weather in the first element in the daily array. So check that DailyWeather is correct, maybe it should be `weather` instead of `Weather`?